# Querying models in django (two levels deep)

Tags: python, django

If I have the following tables

```
class Town(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()

class Street(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
    created = models.DateTimeField()

class House(models.Model):
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

How do I get all the `House`s in a `Town` if I have the name/id of the town?

Answer (score 17):

This should do the trick:

```
town_id = 5
houses_in_town = House.objects.filter(street__town__id = town_id)
```